# Error message in typescript saying that function parameters don't match @TypeScript 0.9.1

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

```
document.getElementById("someElement").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    this._output.innerHTML = this.add(
        parseInt(this._x.value),
        parseInt(this._y.value)
    ).toString();
```

If you take a look at the above statement, you can see that it is simply some HTML that is used to attach an event-listener to a piece of DOM. Below is some code that does the same thing:

```
document.getElementById("someElement").addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    this._output.innerHTML = this.add(
        parseInt(this._x.value),
        parseInt(this._y.value)
    ).toString();
});
```

Here is the problem, in the first code sample, TypeScript does not give me any error, meaning that all paremeters for `addEventListener` match. However, when I use the second one, there seems to be a problem. Typescript says, "Argument Types do not match paremeters".

What can I do to fix this. I am using Typescript 0.9.1 with Webstorm 7.0 EAP.

### UPDATE 1

So, I've fixed my initial problem by changing the code to the following, after looking at the main declaration file in typescript:

```
document.getElementById("Add").addEventListener('click',(event):void => {
    this._output.innerHTML = this.add(
        parseInt(this._x.value),
        parseInt(this._y.value)
    ).toString();
```

If you take a look, I just added a return type. Now, I have a new problem: Typescript complains that `this._output` is an unresolved variable. This is my full typeScript class:

```
class Calculator {
    private _x:HTMLInputElement;
    private _y:HTMLInputElement;
    private _output:HTMLSpanElement;

    constructor (xID: string, yID: string, outputID: string) {
        this._x = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById(xID);
        this._y = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById(yID);
        this._output = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById(outputID);

        this.makeCalculator();
    }

    add (x: number, y: number) {
        return x + y;
    }

    subtract (x: number, y: number) {
        return x - y;
    }

    makeCalculator () {
        document.getElementById("Add").addEventListener('click',(event):void => {
            this._output.innerHTML = this.add(
                parseInt(this._x.value),
                parseInt(this._y.value)
            ).toString();
        });
        document.getElementById("Subtract").addEventListener('click', (event):void => {
            this._output.innerHTML = this.subtract(
                parseInt(this._x.value),
                parseInt(this._y.value)
            ).toString();
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to make a simple calculator in typescript.

Comment: the code is OK; this is a bug in WebStorm - please vote for [this ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8924)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use the lexically escaped value of `this` (which refers to the class) as well we as the context value of this (e.g the `this` inside a jquery callback which refers to the element that raised the event etc). You cannot use fat arrow / lambdas `()=>{}`. You use function, and store `this` for the class variable yourself.

However in your code I see that you only want to use `this` which refers to the class so a lambda `()=>{}` is sufficient for your case. Your code compiles fine: [Check it online](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Calculator%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_x%3aHTMLInputElement;%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_y%3aHTMLInputElement;%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_output%3aHTMLSpanElement;%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%20%28xID%3a%20string,%20yID%3a%20string,%20outputID%3a%20string%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._x%20=%20%3CHTMLInputElement%3E%20document.getElementById%28xID%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._y%20=%20%3CHTMLInputElement%3E%20document.getElementById%28yID%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._output%20=%20%3CHTMLInputElement%3E%20document.getElementById%28outputID%29;%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.makeCalculator%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20add%20%28x%3a%20number,%20y%3a%20number%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20x%20+%20y;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20subtract%20%28x%3a%20number,%20y%3a%20number%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20x%20-%20y;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20makeCalculator%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.getElementById%28%22Add%22%29.addEventListener%28%27click%27,%28event%29%3avoid%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._output.innerHTML%20=%20this.add%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20parseInt%28this._x.value%29,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20parseInt%28this._y.value%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29.toString%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.getElementById%28%22Subtract%22%29.addEventListener%28%27click%27,%20%28event%29%3avoid%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._output.innerHTML%20=%20this.subtract%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20parseInt%28this._x.value%29,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20parseInt%28this._y.value%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29.toString%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D).

Comment: You said "Typescript complains that this._output is an unresolved variable." In the link I shared it doesn't. I don't see the error you want resolved :)